# How to optimize this method with System.arraycopy?

Tags: java, arrays

What's a more efficient way of writing this method:

```
static Foo[][] copy2D(Foo[][] in)
{
    Foo[][] ret = new Foo[in.length][in[0].length];
    for(int i = 0;i < in.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j < in[0].length;j++) {
            ret[i][j] = in[i][j].clone();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you did **not** have the clone() you could replace the inner *for* with:

```
System.arraycopy( in[i], 0, ret[i], 0, in[0].length );
```

But since you're creating a new object in your innermost loop I don't see any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe apache [commons](http://commons.apache.org/) library which contains the class ArrayUtilsmay help you, but I noticed that you may encounter an IndexOutOfBoundException if this statement is valid:

(in[1](http://commons.apache.org/).length || in[2].length || in[n-1].length) < in[0].length

P.S. I know the statement is not syntactically correct, but it gives you an idea of the problem ;)